# How to change the Object in Geometry Nodes with keyframes?

Tags: geometry-nodes, keyframes

To put it simply, I need to change the Object in a specific frame. For example: in frame $0$ the object Info node is **Sphere**, but in frame $20$, the object Info node is **Cube**. How can I do it??

I am considering the *Collection Info node* and keyframe the value to separate Object in Collection. But I can't find the way?

[image]

Comment: Should the objects just instantly switch from one frame to next or transition smoothly from one to the other over time?

Comment: it's best to transform smoothly but I know it's quite complicated. So instantly is good enough for me

Comment: The question would be if you want to do this with any arbitrary shapes or with cube and sphere? Or at least one of the shapes is a,sphere?

Comment: I want it with any object, regardless of the different verticles. Actually, I find the video that has the effect that I want, but I honestly can't follow what he's doing. https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=9ubfb2K6mL0&list=PLEJJbqrScCaDOkg-Aucf0KJBznh-lv2qd&index=2&t=14s

Comment: Well, for any shape it is not so very easy. So this question is better be answered with a full tutorial instead of a short explanation here since this site is more about trying to solve specific issues. So, if in the video he does what you want it would be best to tell ask a new question where you explain with which part you struggle so we could try to help there. Just generally saying you cannot follow is a bit too broad, we cannot completely renarrate the tutorial and thus hoping to make it understandable.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You have several possibilities here...

In all cases, you need the `Scene Time` node, which gives you the current frame.

Furthermore you have to compare this value with the node `Compare` to select the desired frame.

With this selection you have the following possibilities:

1. Selection of objects from a collection and the option *Pick Instance*:

   [image]
2. Direct switching of the geometry:

   [image]

PS: If you want the objects to be kept after frame 20, you would have to switch the node `Compare` from *Equal* to *Greater Than or Equal*.

Comment: Thanks, I have tried it. But you don't mention that I need to make a single Verticle for the Geometry Nodes. I use a Sphere and my Blender shut down many times. Until I find the reason, thanks anyway. If you know the way to transform smoothly, not instantly. I am happy to know what your way is

Comment: @Iampoor Blending two shapes is only possible if both shapes (Cube & Sphere) have exactly the same mesh topology ...which is rather unlikely.

Comment: Yeah I know, and this is the main problem. Two different objects with different verticles. It's really hard to morph between them. So I right now use the way of transforming object 1 to SPHERE, then from SPHERE to object 2.