# Switch geometry node with captured attribute

Tags: geometry-nodes

Why is it impossible to use Switch with Capture Attribute? The connection becomes red. My goal was to use different shape every second point on resampled curve.[image]

Comment: Maybe related: [Why is there a red line when I try to connect one node to another?](https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/274557/why-is-there-a-red-line-when-i-try-to-connect-one-node-to-another/274558#274558)

Comment: Just use `Instance on Points` instead of `Switch`.

Comment: I do not understand how could the Instance on Points alone switch between two meshes. I have this node after Capture Attribute above (the top green connection) , and hoped to input the Switch into its Instance socket.

Comment: Here are two use cases: https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/291388/how-to-change-the-object-in-geometry-nodes-with-keyframes/291391#291391 Basically you would have to enable *Pick Instance* and then provide the index on *Instance Index*

Comment: 'Pick Instance' is the key.. btw if you feed a collection to that, it will automatically cycle through the collection's  elements: https://imgur.com/a/kIPrwBj You can just link the objects to the collection, if you don't want to screw up an existing organisation.